# Configure UITableView with different number of rows in different sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView which has multiple sections and I want each section to have a different number of rows. What I have in code right now is

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //habitsByDay is a global array contain the number of rows for each section, 
    //with each index of the array corresponding to the each of the sections
    return habitsByDay.removeAtIndex(0)
}
```

Will this method be called when each section is loaded (i.e. it should be called `habitsByDay.count`-many times).

Comment: This approach is not correct. Show your main array of data source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table view data source methods can be called at any time, in any order.
In particular, they should not have side effects as in your example.

If `habitsByDay` is an array with the number of rows for each section
then just do

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return habitsByDay[section]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use if statements for that.
For example:

```
if (section == 0) { //First section
return 20; }        //20 rows in first section

if (section == 1) { //Second section
return 10; }        //10 rows in second section
```

Or in your case for example.

```
if (section == 0) {
return habitsByDay.count }
```